# How to set root privilege for tarfile module in python?

Tags: python, extract, root, tar, tarfile

This is my code:

```
gitlab_restore = tarfile.open("PATH/gitconf.tar")
gitlab_restore.extract("/opt/destination/path")
gitlab_restore.close()
```

When I run it this error occurred

```
2021-11-07 09:44:37,139 - root - ERROR - [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/destination/path'
```

How can I set root permission for the tarfile module to write on /opt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Instead, the user that runs the script should have root privileges. Something like this in your example:

`sudo python my_extractor.py`